# Plotly subplot grouped x axis

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I have a subplots of boxplots with different groups in the x-axis. I want to have same color not for different subplots but for different groups in the x-axis. How to do that?

```
x = ['day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1', 'day 1',
     'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2', 'day 2',
     'day 3', 'day 3', 'day 3', 'day 3', 'day 3', 'day 3']
cat = go.Box(
    x=x,
    y=np.random.randn(18)-1,
    name='cat',
    marker=dict(
        outliercolor='rgba(255,0,0,0)'
    )

)
dog = go.Box(
    x=x,
    y=np.random.randn(18)*1000,
    name='dog',
    marker=dict(
        outliercolor='rgba(255,0,0,250)'
    )
)

fig = tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.append_trace(cat, 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(dog, 1, 2)

fig['layout'].update(height=600, width=1000, title='cats and dogs day1-3')
py.iplot(fig, filename='simple-subplot-with-annotations')
```

Alternatively, I can add all traces into a `list`-type variable to create different color for every group (which is day1, day2, day3) but the y-axis scale is so different for each group and that would  make my plot to be unclear for 1 type of trace (ie. `cat` has much lower value range compared to `dog`).

Comment: I do not fully understand what you want, but can suggest to see [here](https://plot.ly/python/subplots/#stacked-subplots-with-a-shared-xaxis). Maybe create shared axis can help you avoid problem about big difference between two traces